# Shiny app fails after successful building of reports

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app (gists below)

[failing server.R](https://gist.github.com/stevenranney/0303311ce9752efb1160710b8bb811c6)

[failing ui.R](https://gist.github.com/stevenranney/784384cd319e4056e60341dd5ef9302a)

that takes input, queries a database, builds an `.Rmd` file into a beamer presentation, and writes out an `.xlsx` file of data. All of these steps happen successfully: the `.Rmd` file is knitted and converted to `pdf` and the `.xlsx` file is written to the appropriate location. The last step is to offer up both of these files for download a `.zip` archive. Once the files are built and stored appropriately, the app crashes and the "Download Report" button does not render.

[image]

In trying to replicate the problem in a "fresh" app to present to SO, I couldn't. I have a near-identical app

[working server.R](https://gist.github.com/stevenranney/fdcb6dd4c377fef5ce5504c9b4c3d343)

[working ui.R](https://gist.github.com/stevenranney/564a6b4e002125b847c0c39b671d481e)

(identical except for the report being rendered) that functions without error. The report builds, the `.xlsx` file is stashed appropriately, and the `.zip` archive is offered for download.

I'm missing something somewhere, but I don't know where it is. I'm inclined to think that it's something in the `.Rmd` file that I'm knitting in the failing app but given it renders successfully, I have no idea what could be going on and there's not much of an error in the app itself, other than the `Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero`.

Can someone point me in the direction of whatever it is I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that while the report was being built successfully, I was not getting the

[image]

`Output created: ...` line. Further investigation of the `output_format$post_processor` statement in the failing shiny app output led me to investigate the `output_format` in the `render()` statement. That took me to how I was instantiating the YAML `output` in the `.Rmd` file.

I had been using

```
output: [my custom latex package]::[my custom format]
```

whereas I should have used

```
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "[my custom format]"
```

With these changes my app now runs successfully.